# IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing an AWS Lambda application. When the job get triggered its failing with the below exception.

`IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError<br>java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR<br> at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:78)<br>    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359)<br> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)<br>  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)<br>   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)<br>    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)<br>   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)<br> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)<br> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)<br>  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)<br>  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.&lt;init&gt;(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:95)<br>   at com.expedia.www.eps.jobs.air.offline.cancel.sync.common.SpringApplicationContext.setContext(SpringApplicationContext.java:11)<br>    at com.expedia.www.eps.jobs.air.offline.cancel.sync.Lambda.handler(Lambda.java:21)<br>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)<br>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`

These are the spring versions available in my pom.xml

```
        <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring. Don't. Spring Boot 2.2.0 relies on Spring 5.2, hence you are mixing 4.3 and 5.2, this will obviously not work. Either downgrade Sprign Data or upgrade Spring. But if you are using Spring Boot why are you iuncluding so many dependencies?

Comment: Thank This issue has been resolved, when I removed unwanted dependancies.

Comment: using 2.2.5 of spring-data-cassandra with spring-context 5.2.5 will fix it or revert to 2.0.x version. The error is coming from spring-data-common.